# Changing content type from a sp2013 app using REST

Tags: content-type, 2013, app

I'm creating an app that uses a calendar and its events as a source for information. My app, however, needs some additional fields associated with the event. The additional fields are easy to create by changing the event content type manually, but I am looking for a solution where I can deploy the extended event content type only where needed and from code.
Is there a way I can do this?